# Does DM-script have lazy evaluation?

Tags: lazy-evaluation, dm-script

I am wondering if there is no lazy evaluation in dm-script?

---

I have the following code fragment that checks, if a `TagGroup` is valid. It throwns an error telling me the `TagGroup` is not defined so the `TagGroupCountTags()` function cannot be exeucted on this `TagGroup`. But that is the purpose of this fragment, checking if the `TagGroup` and the `index` are valid.

I tried to debug the code. The first statement `tg.TagGroupIsValid()` returns false, `0 <= index` of course too. Why is the `tg.TagGroupCountTags()` still being executed? I can't beleave there is no lazy evaluation.

```c
number index = -1; // of course this is not set to -1 in my original code, this is just for demonstration
TagGroup tg;

clearResults();
result(tg.TagGroupIsValid() + "\n"); // resturns 0
result((0 <= index) + "\n"); // returns 0

if(tg.TagGroupIsValid() && 0 <= index && index < tg.TagGroupCountTags()){
    result("Valid.");
}
else{
    result("Invalid.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, conditions in DM-Script are always completely evaluated (no lazy evaluation), so you have to put the If-clauses in a nested way. This is also true if you're using a tertiary operator (?).

Comment: I didn't expect that. And I still wonder why I didn't find that out a lot earlier. But doesn't matter... Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @miile7 Yeah, it's one of the nuisances of DM-scripting. Only only notices it though, when one comes to scripts which need to check validity of objects before doings something with it. That's already pretty advanced scripting.